# UV Mapping in Blend for Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, xaml, blender, uv-mapping, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to use a model that I created in Blender in a WPF application.  In Blender everything works/looks great.

When I export to .OBJ the UV mappings are completely lost, resulting in the textures being applied incorrectly.  I've read up on UV mapping in XAML and the concepts make sense (1:1 ratio for Texture Points to Geometry Points), but is there a way to do the mapping in Expression Blend 4 itself?  Having to figure out the mapping manually seems like a horrible way to do it.

Comment: I've done it like [this way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xg0p-5TJ46k) and not seen to much difference and nothing that couldn't be tweaked. Anything you doing different?

Comment: I've tried that exact process and the UV mappings still end up jumbled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution that worked reliably was Zam3D.  It's extremely expensive for a hobbyist, so I'm still looking for additional solutions, but in the short term (using their free demo period) I was able to get the models I needed mapped correctly.

EDIT:
After further investigation I switched from using the ViewPort3D to the Helix3D Toolkit.  It's a third party library - which I generally try to avoid, but it's almost a drop-in replacement for the existing Viewport3D.  If you're having issues getting XAML 3D objects, or converting your objects to XAML's 3D format, Helix3D supports 3DS - precluding the need to do any conversion.

Helix3d: http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/